How to mock a WebSocket connection using WireMock.Net in .NET Core (c#)
We are using WireMock.net to configure a http server against which we are running integration tests. Our app supports websocket connection and we need to write tests to cover this functionality.
Do you have any idea how to configure an endpoint in WireMock that will support websocket connection? I was unable to find any example towards this implementation.

There is no support for websocket: https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net?tab=readme-ov-file
